# Allow NonRoot User to Mount a Particular NTFS External Hard Drive

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, mount, fstab

I have a 4TB external hard drive connected to an Linux server.

The fstab permissions on this drive are set so that only one particular non-root user has access to it:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/CEE0476DE0388DA9/ /mnt/USBexternal ntfs-3g defaults,auto,uid=51343,gid=50432,umask=077 0 0
```

From a remote location, this user has been successful at doing rsync backups to this external hard drive.

However, the external drive doesn't stay mounted as reliably as an internal hard drive does. Every couple of days I'm having to login as root do this command:

```
mount -a
```

I would like to give this user the ability to mount this drive, but when the non-root user does mount -a, it tells them they do not have permission to do this:

```
nonrootuser@server:~$ mount -a
mount: only root can do that
```

When the non-root user tries to mount this drive specifically, it tells them it is already mounted (even though it isn't):

```
nonrootuser@server:~$ mount /mnt/USBexternal/
mount: according to mtab, /dev/sdb1 is already mounted on /mnt/USBexternal
```

As mentioned, the drive is not actually mounted, but (because of the output above) if the non-root user tries to unmount the drive, it says their request disagrees with fstab:

```
nonrootuser@server:~$ umount /mnt/USBexternal/
umount: /mnt/USBexternal/ mount disagrees with the fstab
```

How can I permit this user the ability to mount this drive, without giving them any other administrative powers?

Comment: check `setfacl`. You can give permissions to the user to only the level for which they need.

Comment: Can you show us what the fstab entry looks like?

Comment: /dev/disk/by-uuid/CEE0476DE0388DA9/ /mnt/USBexternal ntfs-3g defaults,auto,uid=51343,gid=50432,umask=077 0 0

Comment: @Ramesh : Given that this is an ntfs drive, do you think your setfacl suggestion would actually work in this case?

Comment: NTFS does not support linux permissions or acl. Probably, you need to edit the question to add that it is a NTFS drive.

Comment: It's unusual for a filesystem to become unmounted while still having an entry in mtab. One reason this can happen is if the kernel detects an inconsistency and unmounts it itself. Can you check for any errors for this fs or drive in /var/log/syslog and /var/log/messages?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks for directing to the logs. Here's an example of the type of entries I see regarding this external hard drive:  Mar  6 09:33:01 server collectd[3905]: uc_update: Value too old: name = server.domain.lan/df/df-mnt-USBexternal; value time = 1394119981; last cache update = 1394119981;

Comment: That entry from `collectd` might just mean that the filesystem wasn't mounted when it checked. See if there are log entries that have the string `kernel` or `ntfs-3g` or `fuse` in them and look like errors. One possibility is that the drive is going offline, so there may be some chatter about usb disconnections.

Comment: There also ought to be a command to run the equivalent of an `fsck` on the ntfs filesystem (do this only when it's not mounted); hopefully someone else reading this can recommend something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup an entry in the `/etc/sudoers` file for this user to be able to use the mount command.  Add something like the following to the end of the `/etc/sudoers` file:

> `username ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mount, /sbin/mount.ntfs-3g, /usr/bin/umount`

Be sure that the exact path to each executable is correct for your system.  For example, your `mount` command might be in `/bin` instead of `/usr/bin`.

Adding the `mount.ntfs-3g` part is important to provide that access for the user.  I can see in your mount command that you are using a **ntfs-3g** filesystem type.

You could, instead, create a shell script to handle the mounting/unmounting and place that in your sudoers file.  For example:

create `/usr/local/bin/mount-ntfs-drive` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
device_path="/dev/disk/by-uuid/CEE0476DE0388DA9/"
mount_point="/mnt/USBexternal"
if [ "$1" = "-u" ] ; then
  # do unmount
  /bin/umount $mount_point
else
  # do mount
  /bin/mount $device_path $mount_point
fi
```

edit `/etc/sudoers` file:

> `username ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/mount-ntfs-drive`

Be sure to do `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/mount-ntfs-drive`.  Also, when your user runs the file, they will need to use the fully qualified path for it to work.  It might work from their path but not sure.

`sudo /usr/local/bin/mount-ntfs-drive`

Comment: Thanks for specific details on achieving this. I suspect that limiting this user's mount-ability to one specific mount-point is too difficult to achieve, but would like to know your thoughts. You see, to me it seems like what you're suggesting would also give the user the ability (if malicious) to mount and umount things outside the scope of this specific external drive. What are your thoughts?

Comment: I added this line to the /etc/sudoers file:                    actualusername ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/mount, /sbin/mount.ntfs-3g, /bin/umount                   but, even after a reboot, the user cannot mount -a.

Comment: you could create a shell script that will do the mounting and unmounting and place that in your sudoers file.  I'll update my answer with the details.

Comment: That did indeed work, when I was typing "mount -a" for this non-root user, I should have been typing "sudo mount -a" Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a script which checks whether the connection is broken and does the necessary clean-up in that case. This script could be executed every 30 minutes as `root` by `cron`.

Maybe is disappears from `/proc/mounts` when the kernel detects that the device has gone. If not then the script could simply try to create a file on the mounted volume.

That would avoid the problem situation you described.

A different approach is to not use the `user` feature of `fstab` but use `sudo` instead so that the user can run a script with superuser privilege which does both the clean-up (if necessary) and the mount.

Comment: 0,15,30,45 * * * * date >> /mnt/USBexternal/mountStamps.txt    ###

I tried this cron writing to the drive every 15 minutes, but this didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @Lonniebiz "Every 15 minutes" can be written as `*/15`, too. This was not intended to prevent losing the connection to the device (which should not happen BTW) but to detect the connection loss.

Comment: Instead of scheduling a cron, it would be ideal if I could permit the user to ensure the drive is mounted before they attempt their backup. Actually, they are initiating this backup via cron on their remote machine (I left that part out to simplify the question). It would be nice if they could add one line to the top of their backup script that would ensure this remote external drive was indeed mounted.

Comment: The problem with sudo for fstab suggestion, is that I don't want other users to be able to see this external drive.

Comment: @Lonniebiz That is a really strange argument as (1) `fstab` is usually world-readable, (2) so is `/proc/mounts` (and `/proc/partitions`), and (3) `lsusb` can be executed by ordinary users (`/sys` is readable for them, too). (4) The only thing ordinary users usually **cannot** read is `/etc/sudoers`...

Comment: If you'll look at the fstab permissions, at the top of my question, you'll see that I've only permitted access for one particular user. If I log in as another user, I cannot access the file system. Only root and that particular user can access it. That's intended.

Comment: @Lonniebiz You meant: The other users may see the drive but not the drive content. That's difference. Why should the `sudo` solution allow other users to see the drive content?

Comment: Perhaps it shouldn't, but I don't want to give every user the ability to mount or umount this drive. I'm trying to limit this ability to one particular user and root.

Comment: @Lonniebiz It seems you don't know how `sudo` works. Given that it is not only a solution for this case but also in general a tool of great importance you really should have a look at `man sudoers`.

Comment: You are right that I've never looked deeply at sudoers. I'm looking now though. I hope I can achieve this without the user having to type their password, because the ultimate goal is performing these backups automatically using this user's account.